# Firebase retriving a data from Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm trying to retrive a list from the Database and adding it to a ListView, my problem is the event only triggers after onResume() so the array is empty on the onCreate() function. I want to retrive the data on the onCreate() function and create my ListView there here is the code.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("projetos");
private DatabaseReference mProjetoReference;
private ChildEventListener mProjetoListener;

private List<Projeto> projetos;
ListView listaProjetos;
ProjetoDAO projetoDAO;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    projetos = new ArrayList<Projeto>();
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Projeto projeto = new Projeto();
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                projeto = postSnapShot.getValue(Projeto.class);
                projetos.add(projeto);
            }
            //Log.i("TESTEList", "projetos tamanho = " + projetos.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    listaProjetos = findViewById(R.id.lista);
    ArrayAdapter<Projeto> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Projeto>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, projetos);
    listaProjetos.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
```

I don't know if my problem is clear English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code of list and adapter after `for` loop when you have the data to create adapter

```
// for future , accessible in other methods
ArrayAdapter<Projeto> adapter 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    projetos = new ArrayList<Projeto>();
    // for efficiency, time consuming so do it early
    listaProjetos = findViewById(R.id.lista);
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Projeto projeto = new Projeto();
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                projeto = postSnapShot.getValue(Projeto.class);
                projetos.add(projeto);
            }
           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Projeto>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, projetos);
          //  Note : inside anonymous classes use
          // ActivityName.this for context
           listaProjetos.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```